# Address Sanitizer: "Ran out of registers during register allocation"

Tags: c++, xcode, clang

I've been attempting to get address sanitizer working in Xcode to find the source of a memory stomping bug. I've changed my standard compiler to the latest trunk version of Clang, and added `-fsanitize=address` to the compiler and linker flags for the target. However, when building the target, I the the error `Ran out of registers during register allocation`. When building without the `-fsanitize=address` flag I get no problems, only when I use that flag does the problem occur.

What could be the cause of this problem? I've got 16GB of RAM available so I don't think the build is running out of memory, and I can't find an explanation of what this error means anywhere. Could this be a bug in the latest Clang?

Comment: What target are you compiling for? Do you have any assembly code mixed in?

Comment: The first error was located in inline assembly, so I preprocessed that part out and now I'm getting errors that don't point to specific lines - 3 instances of "ran out of registers" just after the following warning: `'operator delete' is missing exception specification 'throw()'`. Could that be something to do with it?

Comment: Keep fixing bugs and see if the problem goes away.